# Jenkins could not load definitions from resource AntTasks.properties

Tags: python, ant, jenkins

**demo is here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/opensource/os-ecant/**

I want to run this demo on the Jenkins, but build failed.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\antPythonTry1
Updating https://localhost/svn/test at revision '2014-10-30T11:06:06.839 +0800'
At revision 1
no change for https://localhost/svn/test since the previous build
[antPythonTry1] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\antPythonTry1\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource pyAntTasks.properties. It could not be found.

compile:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\antPythonTry1\build.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type py-compile
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You're missing the jar containing the pyANT tasks. This needs to be located somewhere where ANT can pick it up on startup, typically $ANT_HOME/lib or $HOME/.ant/lib

Comment: yeah you're right, i've added pyANT tasks

Answer (score 1):

added pyAntTasks-1.3.3.jar in "apache-ant-1.9.2\lib"